# How can I revoke an app's permission to access USB after granting it permanently?

Tags: permissions, usb-host-mode

I have an app that requested USB access, and when prompted I selected "Yes, allow this app to use USB" and checked the "permanently" checkbox.

Now I would like to revoke this permission so that the app would always have to ask every time it wants to use USB.

Is to possible to do that by changing something in system settings? Where? Is there a permission manager built-in to the system? If not, then is it available as an external app?

I'm using a tablet running Android version 4.1.1.

Comment: Are you sure your *app* was causing that popup? What Android version are you using? My guess is something higher than 4.1, and you are referring to the ADB security popup to always accept the *computer* as a safe counterpart. Could that be?

Comment: I'm referring to a popup when you request for a permission. To be precise by calling a function requestPermission(UsbDevice device, PendingIntent pi) from UsbManager class

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Then the answer is probably to be found in [How to stop Android asking for permission before permitting access to USB device](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/39851/16575): *the box should never display again (unless the software is uninstalled and then reinstalled)* If you're looking for a way to do that programmatically (i.e. with code from your app), you'd better ask at [SO], as our site focuses on *end user issues*.

Comment: I second this bein on-topic. Don't get confused by the *word* "developing" alone: developers are able to act as users, I've been told and tend to believe :) This question is clearly from a user's perspective (how to undo a "use always" setting).