# "Read phone status and identity" privacy issue

Tags: permissions, privacy

Multiple apps released in my country require the `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` permission which means not only they get to know my phone number, they also get my [IMEI](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48709/read-phone-state-and-identity). My second concern is that I have apps which are *not* even related to banking, financials or anything like that, which use this permission and that's just outrageous.

Is there any method in Android to prevent apps from doing that?

I'm a legitimate user, I have my own phone but I don't want to grant access to this data to companies which are leaking customer data left and right.

The only solution I can think of is having an Android VM on my PC, e.g. Android x86 and using these apps in it which is quite tiresome (and I've verified it works).

My phone is not rooted but if there are root related options, I'd like to hear them out.

Of course, there's [Virtual Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pspace.vandroid) made in China by God knows whom which is basically an entire Android 7.1 but I'm not ready to trust it yet.

Comment: On Android 10+ regular apps can no longer access IMEI.

Comment: As Firelord stated rooting fails the SafetyNet attestation; however, using Magisk has its own advantages ;) I'm on Android 10 with root and Xposed framework with all the banking apps working like a charm. SafetyNet is pretty easy to pass with Magisk. In fact, I use Pixelify GPhotos for unlimited google photos storage by faking it to be Pixel 5. I don't really need that but it's good to have it

Comment: Just a second thought.. the apps work fine even if you reject the permission which they don't necessarily utilize. In case you always allow all the permissions asked for. Like calculator asking for Phone permission

Comment: @Robert can you say more about this particular permission? Can apps still read my phone number? I have an old SIM card which includes it but strangely a newer one does not. Actually Android 11 already hides the phone number but only for apps "If your app targets Android 11": https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions

Comment: @44yu5h the apps I use ask for this permission specifically. Of course, I can unpack them, edit manifests, sign them again but I will have to do that for up to seven installed apps which is a chore.

Comment: Google enforces that new apps and app updates have a certain targetSDK. "app targets Android 11" means a minimum targetSDK value of 30. According to [this](https://medium.com/the-web-tub/android-target-api-level-requirements-have-been-updated-b455fab2dea7) all app updates that have been published after Nov. 1st 2021 have to target Android 11 or higher.

Comment: I've just run DevInfo https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.liuzh.deviceinfo on Android 11 and it happily reads my phone number. Darn. The app was last updated a week ago or so. `IMEI` is at least restricted.