# Android permission and ProtectionLevel

Tags: applications, permissions

How Do we find what level of Android permission is required for a specific permission.

Lets say we have `android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER`([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER))

What permission group does it fall into?([docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html))

- Regular
- Dangerous
- System or Signed
- Signed

Comment: Is this a development question?

Comment: @dotVezz not necessarily. The protection level of a permission also tells you whether the app gets access to those permissions when installed as user-app (e.g. system-or-signed does not in those cases).

Comment: You usually get some first-aid help with issues checking their tag-wikis, in your case [permissions tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/permissions/info) will get you started, and tell you to take a look at [What do the permissions that applications require mean?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38388/16575) – where you will find exactly the answer to your question.

Comment: Protection Levels might differ between Android versions (and even devices/ROM versions). More pointers: https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms – you can use e.g. *Android Census* to check for those differences, e.g. `https://census.tsyrklevich.net/permissions/android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY`