# Can somebody explain how multi-user is implemented in android 4.4

Tags: multi-user

Can somebody please help in giving information on how multi-user partition is achieved on android 4.4.

I was digging into 4.4 code specific to creating multiple users.

There is class called multiUser(added in 4.4 for multi-user) whose members talk with multiUserService to create user space.

I am not getting how exactly secure space is created at file system.

I have below basic question.
1. How FileSystem partition is achieved for multiple users
2. How UI part ( Launcher, different screen icons etc)  is developed and when user switch how it reload default users data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works in a very similar way to how one user's apps are isolated from each other. Whereas apps' private data used to be stored in `/data/data`, now it's stored in `/data/users/n`, where n is the ID of the user profile. Each user gets their own directory, and each app that user uses gets a directory within that. POSIX file system permissions protect the data directories, not only from other apps, but also from other users.

Because Android uses the existing POSIX process, UID, and file system security mechanism, the same way it does for different apps, the implementation is already secure without needing anything special at the OS level, or a more complicated (and thus battery-hungry) solution such as virtualization. Virtualization would work poorly for this anyway: providing virtualized access to the network, Bluetooth, NFC hardware, etc. such that all users could control it would add a lot of unnecessary complexity to the driver stacks.

When both users run the same app (such as the launcher), there are actually two instances of that app. They share one APK file, but they have two separate processes running under different POSIX user IDs, and they each look in their own data directory. This way, nothing they might write to is shared between the two users, but read-only parts (such as the app's executable code from the APK file) are shared, reducing RAM and storage use. Both instances might be running at once, and switching users just changes which one is the foreground app on the screen. Nothing needs to be reloaded or restarted.

This works the same way whether the app is a built-in one, or one installed by the user. There's an awkward side-effect of that: when one user upgrades an app, the upgrade affects all users, even if the new version needs more permissions.

Only apps with the INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS permission are special. Such apps get access to APIs within the Android framework to look at all the users' data directories at once. The lock screen is an example of such an app: in one instance, it needs to be able to read each user's settings and profile picture, in order to show the "switch users" GUI.

Comment: If you have any further, more specific questions, feel free to click the **Ask Question** button to ask them. Comments aren't a place for long follow-up discussions, only for seeking clarification if the answer isn't clear.

Comment: Hello Dan Hulme, Thanks for your nice explanation. I have few more things in mind, 1. Native applications being shared ( eg - Contacts, call log, camera, gallery etc) in multiple users and only their data is separated or package manager makes new copy of these apks into user space and install apks newly  ?     2. For multi-user android is there any OS virtulization technology used like - ThinVisor, Hypervisor etc or it run on same android OS ? I will be great full if you suggest any code path related to multi-user for study