# What is the advantage of making f-droid a system app?

Tags: system-apps, f-droid

F-droid (0.7) has two options:

One to grant it "root" powers, and another to give it "system-app" powers.

Just using it as a "root" app will let it install apps without going through the whole "Are you sure you want to install this app" page.

What does System-app give it?

I can't test it as it crashes on my phone

Answer (score 2):

I believe this was/is a planned feature for F-Droid, which would essentially give it features similar to the play store where it can auto-update apps, install them and remove them all by itself, without needing user interaction. See [this](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.fdroid.fdroid.privileged) as an explanation - it's the extension which was meant to give F_Droid these priviledges, but as it says in the description:

> Note: This is still in a testing phase. Current F-Droid versions do not yet interact with this extension.

Answer (score -1):

Information from the [F-Droid Site](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=de.j4velin.systemappmover):

This is for an app called *System App Mover*, but it's description is correct.

> System apps can get more privileges, so some apps get more
>   functionality when installed as a system app.
>
> On the other hand, system apps can not be uninstalled. So this app can
>   also be used to convert system apps to normal user apps by moving them
>   from the /system/app directory to /data/app directory.
>
> **WARNING: Uninstalling important system apps might result in a unusable
>   device! Use this function at your own risk and only if you know what
>   you're doing!**

See [What do android application permissions mean](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38388/what-do-android-application-permissions-mean). There are some permissions that have a "level" of "system". Those can only be used by applications that are "system" applications. I do not know why f-droid would need them. Maybe the *INSTALL_PACKAGES* permission. This would allow f-driod to install an application, like Google Play does, instead of sending the Install request off to the Package Manager application.

Comment: *System apps can get more privileges, so some apps get more functionality when installed as a system app.* What extra privileges does f-droid need that root doesn't give it?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a little more information pertaining to your comment.