# How to make alternative app markets perform automatic updates?

Tags: updates, application-autoupdate, alternative-markets

I have tried F-Droid and the Amazon App Store, but I had to confirm every update manually. Is there a way to make any alternative app markets (i.e. not Google Play Store) auto-update in the background, without prompting me?

Comment: Have you tried the Amazon app store? It's focused on normal users, not power users (who are more likely to want to control their updates), so it might have the options you seek.

Comment: As I wrote in the question I tried the Amazon store and it doesn't support auto updates.

Comment: Not sure if you can do it (maybe by side loading and even then might not be compatible) but the native "app stores" for both my Samsung device and LG support auto updating. If you can get one of them installed, they might run and have most apps available in Play Store on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of them other stores will be able to auto-update your apps unless you are rooted.
Other apps cannot install new apps without root access.

If you do have root access,
1Mobile(1mobile.com) store has this feature. Mobogenie is out there, too, but it has more ads.

Comment: Good points with the install-permission implication (+1). As at least the *F-Droid* app also offers a "root-mode": have you tested/hear-of whether it supports auto-updates when "converted into a system app" (see: [What is the advantage of making f-droid a system app?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/83787/16575)) At least there's [an issue open for that on GitLab](https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroidclient/issues/106).