# What is the Android Permission "WRITE_GSERVICES" doing?

Tags: stock-android, permissions

There is a mysterious and undocumented Android Permission called: **WRITE_GSERVICES**. As usual Googles own documentation is even more mysterious than any bad fairytale, writing:

```
android.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES      Allows an application to modify the Google service map.
```

However Googling (!) for `Google Service Map` yields nothing useful.

**What is it controlling and what is it used for?**

Comment: @Ryan: If you've actually bothered to look at the link you say are duplicated, you'd see that is not the case. And where do you see it has to do with the map data? Sources seem to tell another story.

Comment: Well it simply isn't and I don't see you even trying to back up your statement with any code, proof or relevant links, not your own. Please, show me the code that show it is even remotely connected to Google Maps. As I said, my own investigation show something else.

Comment: [While this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464136/android-google-maps-api-v2-requires-permission-that-it-already-has) (And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682538/when-to-use-read-gservices-permission)) is for `READ_GSERVICES`, which makes sense, since normal applications cannot request access to `WRITE_GSERVICES`, the asker points out that Google Maps requires the READ_GSERVICES permission to work correctly. - Also want to add, of the 17 edits to the duplicate that you call 'mine', 14 of them were by other users than myself, contributing to over 5000 characters added.

Comment: Yes, and thanks. That first link seem very relevant and confirm that it has something to do with any or all of the close to hundred different Services that Google can provide to AOS. Everything from Billing and Ads to Play and Cloud services. The problem here (that I was hoping to resolve) was to get a more specific example of where and how this one permission is used by Google, since it is very intrusive, and could easily pose a security threat.

Comment: See: http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms#WRITE_GSERVICES :) "Allows an application to modify the Google service map." So @RyanConrad It's the *service map*, not "Google Maps Service". What exactly is meant by this is another thing, as to my knowledge no real documentation exists.

Comment: I vote to re-open this question. For the reasoning, please see (and join the discussion on) Meta: [Shall we really close questions on permission meanings as duplicates to the “general list”?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1880/16575)

Comment: Just want to add [this](http://i.imgur.com/oTmb7UU.png) picture of some of the services, packages offered by Google. (This was taken from a ROM GAPPS plugin list.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sup>Note this permission is almost completely undocumented, hence we need to feel our way to its real meaning. So this is in no way an "authoritative answer" – but more or less something between a "good guess" and a "deduction from other pointers".</sup>

The official description for this permission (as said, there's no further documentation) is:

> Allows an application to modify the Google service map.

So now we can guess what that's supposed to mean. Let's do some "reverse engineering" for that to feel our way into it. [Ryan already gave some pointers](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98330/what-is-the-android-permission-write-gservices-doing#comment122325_98330) in his comment, linking to two SO questions:

- [Android Google Maps API v2 - Requires permission that it already has](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20464136/2533433) (in our context: Maps API requires `READ_GSERVICES`)
- [When to use READ_GSERVICES permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22682538/2533433)

Reading between the lines: Whenever an app wants to use (parts of) the *Google Services Framework*, it must declare the `READ_GSERVICES` permission required – which is pretty much similar to requiring `GET_ACCOUNTS` if you want to `USE_CREDENTIALS`: the app first needs to ensure the required service is available at all, before accessing it.

This gives us an idea of what the *Google Service Map* must be: some kind of index for available (installed) Google Services.

Now that we discovered that, we can make a good guess what the `WRITE_GSERVICES` permission might be intended for – and why it is protected by the `system` protection level (meaning, it's only granted to "system apps" – i.e. those integrated into the ROM, which is being installed on the `/system` partition): If `READ_GSERVICES` is intended to figure out which Google services are available, `WRITE_GSERVICES` must be its counter-part to *update* that service map. Which is e.g., whenever a new service was installed (or removed), to update the "index of Google Services available on the device" – the "Google Service Map".

Just one thing I wonder in this context is, why [this permission belongs to the `ACCOUNTS` group](http://androidpermissions.com/permission/com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES) …

---

See also:

- [Google Play Services Requirements](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/googleplayservices) (especially the chapter "Specifying additional permissions")
- [Maps API v2 and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-developers/1318gf74nt/maps-api-v2-and-write-external-storage-permission) describes the `READ_GSERVICES` permission as "Allows the
  API to ***access Google web-based services***" (quoting a message from the `android-developers@googlegroups.com` mailing list)
- [Google Service Map: Karte des Google-Netzwerks](https://www.googlewatchblog.de/2007/07/google-service-map-karte-des-google-netzwerks/) (a German article preceding Android) describes the "Google Service Map" as "listing of all available Google services". Note that, though similar in terms, this might be something different – but it makes much sense. See the complete list [here](http://logiciels.zorgloob.com/liste.php). And it might explain why this permission belongs to the `ACCOUNTS` group, as it includes e.g. [Google Account Authentication](http://logiciels.zorgloob.com/accountapi-voir.php) ;)
- SO: [What is Android Permission WRITE_GSERVICES exactly for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18497203/2533433) (again points out this refers to [Google Web Services](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/))

Comment: Another point why this permission might be in the `ACCOUNTS` group: many Google services require a login to be usable, so there might be some cross-checking (e.g. transmitting your account *name* to check if you've got an "active user" for a given service, even without logging you in/transmitting a password/AUTH-token).