# Unknown Permissions on VirusTotal analysis

Tags: stock-android, google-account, permissions, system-apps

I have noticed unusual and unwanted behavior from a few of my system apps, most notably Google Play Services, Google Account Manager,  and Google Services Framework. These apps cause force closes on their own operations as well as those of other apps, they seem to have the capability to take over functionality of my phone completely at times.

So, I used the Virustotal.com tool to analyze permissions on these apps to determine if they are present with the right capabilities built into them for the version that came pre-installed on the phone. For each of these apps, they returned between 10-20 additional permissions each that they were not designed to have, suggesting that they have been tampered with.

My phone is not rooted or modified in any way and I have had it for less than a year.  These additional permissions were labeled:

> (Unknown permission from android reference)

designating these specific permissions as not being native to these apps. Some of these permissions are specifically designed for transmission and communication of data via C2DM and Gtalk to other devices, as well as exposure of saved account details including passwords. This leads me to conclude that sensitive personal information has been leaked to third parties. Here is the output for Google Account Manager as an example:

```
VirusTotal
SHA256:     602db0ceb05877fb6996fd2a3510721d0e32463a6e784ba5cc60ae1f71bb3226
File name:  GoogleLoginService.apk
Detection ratio:    0 / 53
Analysis date:  2014-07-20 19:04:51 UTC ( 9 months, 1 week ago )
0
0

    Analysis
    File detail
    Additional information
    Comments 0
    Votes
    Behavioural information

The file being studied is Android related! APK Android file more specifically. The application's main package name is com.google.android.gsf.login. The internal version number of the application is 19. The displayed version string of the application is 4.4.4-1215936. The minimum Android API level for the application to run (MinSDKVersion) is 8. The target Android API level for the application to run (TargetSDKVersion) is 17.
Risk summary
The studied DEX file makes use of API reflection
Permissions that allow the application to access Internet
Permissions that allow the application to access private information
Other permissions that could be considered as dangerous in certain scenarios
Required permissions
android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE (change network connectivity)
android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS (read sync settings)
com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES (Unknown permission from android reference)
android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS (use the authentication credentials of an account)
android.permission.DUMP (retrieve system internal status)
android.permission.READ_LOGS (read sensitive log data)
android.permission.WRITE_PROFILE (write the user's personal profile data)
android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE (enable or disable application components)
android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS (read sync statistics)
android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED (automatically start at boot)
android.permission.INTERNET (full Internet access)
com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_MAIL_SWITCH (Unknown permission from android reference)
android.permission.BACKUP (control system back up and restore)
com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.youtube (Unknown permission from android reference)
android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_READ (read subscribed feeds)
android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS (manage the accounts list)
com.google.android.gtalkservice.permission.GTALK_SERVICE (Unknown permission from android reference)
com.google.android.permission.BROADCAST_DATA_MESSAGE (Unknown permission from android reference)
com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.YouTubeUser (Unknown permission from android reference)
android.permission.PERSISTENT_ACTIVITY (make application always run)
com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.ALL_SERVICES (Unknown permission from android reference)
com.android.vending.TOS_ACKED (Unknown permission from android reference)
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE (view network status)
com.google.android.providers.settings.permission.READ_GSETTINGS (Unknown permission from android reference)
com.google.android.providers.settings.permission.WRITE_GSETTINGS (Unknown permission from android reference)
com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH (Unknown permission from android reference)
android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS (write contact data)
android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS (write sync settings)
android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS (act as an account authenticator)
android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY (send sticky broadcast)
com.android.vending.billing.BILLING_ACCOUNT_SERVICE (Unknown permission from android reference)
android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS (modify global system settings)
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE (read phone state and identity)
com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.mail (Unknown permission from android reference)
com.android.vending.INTENT_VENDING_ONLY (Unknown permission from android reference)
com.google.android.providers.talk.permission.READ_ONLY (Unknown permission from android reference)
com.google.android.googleapps.permission.ACCESS_GOOGLE_PASSWORD (Unknown permission from android reference)
com.google.android.providers.talk.permission.WRITE_ONLY (Unknown permission from android reference)
android.permission.VIBRATE (control vibrator)
com.android.chrome.TOS_ACKED (Unknown permission from android reference)
android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_WRITE (write subscribed feeds)
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE (view Wi-Fi status)
com.android.vending.billing.ADD_CREDIT_CARD (Unknown permission from android reference)
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK (prevent phone from sleeping)
android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE (change Wi-Fi status)
android.permission.READ_CONTACTS (read contact data)
com.android.vending.billing.IBillingAccountService.BIND2 (Unknown permission from android reference)
android.permission.READ_PROFILE (read the user's personal profile data)
com.google.android.gtalkservice.permission.SEND_HEARTBEAT (Unknown permission from android reference)
android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS (discover known accounts)
Permission-related API calls
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
Landroid/net/ConnectivityManager;->getActiveNetworkInfo()Landroid/net/NetworkInfo; called from Lcom/google/android/gsf/loginservice/BaseActivity;->hasNetworkConnection()Z
READ_PHONE_STATE
Landroid/telephony/TelephonyManager;->getLine1Number()Ljava/lang/String; called from Lcom/google/android/gsf/login/RecoveryDataActivity;->initViews(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
USE_CREDENTIALS
Landroid/accounts/AccountManager;->invalidateAuthToken(Ljava/lang/String; Ljava/lang/String;)V called from Lcom/google/android/gsf/loginservice/GoogleLoginService$GlsImplementation;->invalidateAuthToken(Ljava/lang/String;)V
INTERNET
Ljava/net/ServerSocket;-><init>(I)V called from Lcom/google/android/common/http/TestHttpServer;-><init>(I)V
Landroid/webkit/WebView;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;)V called from Lcom/google/android/common/GoogleWebContentHelper;->initializeViews()V
Landroid/webkit/WebView;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;)V called from Lcom/google/android/gsf/login/CustomWebView;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;)V
VIBRATE
Landroid/app/NotificationManager;->notify(I Landroid/app/Notification;)V called from Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil;->a(Landroid/content/Context; Ljava/lang/String; Ljava/lang/String; Landroid/os/Bundle;)Ljava/lang/String;
ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
Landroid/net/wifi/WifiManager;->getWifiState()I called from Lcom/google/android/gsf/login/SetupWirelessActivity;->tryEnablingWifi()Z
GET_ACCOUNTS
Landroid/accounts/AccountManager;->getAccountsByType(Ljava/lang/String;)[Landroid/accounts/Account; called from Lcom/google/android/gsf/login/BaseActivity;->isFirstAccount()Z
Landroid/accounts/AccountManager;->getAccountsByType(Ljava/lang/String;)[Landroid/accounts/Account; called from Lcom/google/android/gsf/login/AccountIntroActivity;->maybeSkipAccountSetup()Z
Landroid/accounts/AccountManager;->getAccountsByType(Ljava/lang/String;)[Landroid/accounts/Account; called from Lcom/google/android/gsf/login/EduLoginActivity;->removeAnyNewAccounts()V
READ_SYNC_SETTINGS
Landroid/content/ContentResolver;->getIsSyncable(Landroid/accounts/Account; Ljava/lang/String;)I called from Lcom/google/android/gsf/login/SyncSettingsFragment;->updateListViewData(Landroid/accounts/Account;)V
CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE
Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;->setApplicationEnabledSetting(Ljava/lang/String; I I)V called from Lcom/google/android/gsf/login/ShowErrorActivity;->onClick(Landroid/view/View;)V
MANAGE_ACCOUNTS
Landroid/accounts/AccountManager;->removeAccount(Landroid/accounts/Account; Landroid/accounts/AccountManagerCallback; Landroid/os/Handler;)Landroid/accounts/AccountManagerFuture; called from Lcom/google/android/gsf/login/EduLoginActivity;->removeAnyNewAccounts()V
Landroid/accounts/AccountManager;->removeAccount(Landroid/accounts/Account; Landroid/accounts/AccountManagerCallback; Landroid/os/Handler;)Landroid/accounts/AccountManagerFuture; called from Lcom/google/android/gsf/loginservice/GoogleLoginService$GlsImplementation;->deleteAllAccounts()V
Landroid/accounts/AccountManager;->removeAccount(Landroid/accounts/Account; Landroid/accounts/AccountManagerCallback; Landroid/os/Handler;)Landroid/accounts/AccountManagerFuture; called from Lcom/google/android/gsf/loginservice/GoogleLoginService$GlsImplementation;->deleteOneAccount(Ljava/lang/String;)V
AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS
Landroid/accounts/AccountManager;->getUserData(Landroid/accounts/Account; Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; called from Lcom/google/android/gsf/loginservice/GoogleLoginService;->accountHasFeatures(Landroid/accounts/AccountManager; Landroid/accounts/Account; [Ljava/lang/String;)Z
Activities
com.google.android.gsf.login.AccountIntroActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.AccountPreIntroUIActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.AccountIntroUIActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.PlusQueryActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.PlusFaqActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.NameActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.BadNameActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.PhotoActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.LearnMoreActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.WaitForDeviceCountryActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.CaptchaActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.SetupWirelessIntroActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.SetupWirelessActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.LoginActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.EduLoginActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.UsernamePasswordActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.PrepareAccountSetupActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.LoginActivityTask
com.google.android.gsf.login.ShowErrorActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.SyncIntroActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.CreateAccountActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.PlusActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.PlusCheckTask
com.google.android.gsf.login.UsernameActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.CreateAccountTask
com.google.android.gsf.login.ProfileTask
com.google.android.gsf.login.NameCheckTask
com.google.android.gsf.login.CheckAvailTask
com.google.android.gsf.login.SuggestUsernameActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.VerifyProfileActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.ChoosePasswordActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.RecoveryIntroActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.GetCountryListTask
com.google.android.gsf.login.RecoveryDataActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.AccountSecurityActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.PicassaInfoActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.GoogleServicesActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.TermsOfServiceActivity
com.google.android.gsf.login.BrowserActivity
com.google.android.gsf.loginservice.GrantCredentialsPermissionActivity
Services
com.google.android.gsf.loginservice.GoogleLoginService
Receivers
com.google.android.gsf.login.DevicePolicyActivatedReceiver
Service-related intent filters
com.google.android.gsf.loginservice.GoogleLoginService
actions: android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator, com.google.android.gsf.action.GET_GLS
Activity-related intent filters
com.google.android.gsf.login.AccountIntroActivity
actions: com.google.android.accounts.AccountIntro, android.intent.action.MAIN
categories: android.intent.category.DEFAULT
Receiver-related intent filters
com.google.android.gsf.login.DevicePolicyActivatedReceiver
actions: com.google.android.apps.enterprise.dmagent.AUTO_REGISTRATION_FINISHED
Code-related observations
The application does not load any code dynamically
The application contains reflection code
The application does not contain native code
The application does not contain cryptographic code
Application certificate information
Issuer
    DN: C=US, ST=California, L=Mountain View, O=Google Inc., OU=Android, CN=Android
    C: US
    CN: Android
    L: Mountain View
    O: Google Inc.
    S: California
    OU: Android
Subject
    DN: C=US, ST=California, L=Mountain View, O=Google Inc., OU=Android, CN=Android
    C: US
    CN: Android
    L: Mountain View
    O: Google Inc.
    S: California
    OU: Android
```

Who should I bring this information to the attention to? Is it pretty much certain that my phone is completely compromised?

Answer (score 1):

While there may be something wrong with Google apps' compatibility, it's unlikely that those apps are compromised.

Android SDK (Software Development Kit) provides some standard permissions that are listed on [its official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) (and [some of the details on Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38388/what-do-android-application-permissions-mean)).

In addition to that, Android allows its developers to [declare new permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#declaring) to be used by other apps. As it can be seen, Google does that with an example of Gtalk (`com.google.android.gtalkservice.permission.GTALK_SERVICE`). It's normal for an app (even more, from the same developer) to use custom permissions for their needs.

Now, the reason why VirusTotal labels them as "unknown permission" is because it only checks for standard permissions, which is reasonable since there are no references for *all* custom permissions defined by other apps. (VirusTotal could probably work together with Google or other trusted companies to store their custom permissions as "known", but it's outside of the context).

So the conclusion is, that "unknown permission" doesn't mean the app is tampered with/compromised. It's just not a standard permission from Android SDK. In fact, many other apps also use the same permissions to use Google-provided services, such as C2DM (or GCM, Google Cloud Messaging), GMaps, etc, which are not standard Android permissions (and components).