# Fruit Ninja Wi-Fi permissions

Tags: permissions

I see Fruit Ninja recently added "Wi-Fi connection information" to its ever-growing list of required permissions. I read the little description, but what does it actually mean? Does that mean the name and password to my router are being sent back to their Mothership?

Comment: Is it just me, or is this the final straw for others to uninstall this app? Sure, it's a fun game, but the required permissions never end...

Comment: It's not just you. If I need an app, I always compare what similar apps request, and what seems really needed. If it gets too extensive, I tend to pick a more permission-friendly app even if it has a lower rating. It's good to be sceptical in this context: better safe than sorry, and especially in the "ad-supported app market" abuse risk is not low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password is unlikely to be touched by this. For a few additional details, see e.g. [ACCESS_WIFI_STATE](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms#ACCESS_WIFI_STATE):

> This could be requested by any application that uses internet access. The application may check the state of your connection before trying to access the internet. It's comparable to [ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms#ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE), just for WiFi.

Following up the reference:

> Allows applications to access information about networks, including if a network is available (or just connecting), what type of network the device is connected to, if any (WiFi, 3G, LTE), if it's in Roaming, and also reasons for a failed connection attempt (if any).
> **Good use:** The application may check the state of your connection before trying to access the internet, and e.g. restrict itself to WiFi for some actions.
> **Bad use:** Only in combination with other permissions (e.g. data collection for profiling).

So summed up, this would see things like

- whether WiFi is active (if inactive, nothing else)
- which network is connected (SSID, MAC)
- which networks are available (SSID, MAC)

This permission *alone* cannot send anything anywhere. But the mentioned data collected may be "sent to the mothership" if the app also requested the [INTERNET](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms#INTERNET) permission, or can make use of another app that has access to the network (e.g. send a mail, SMS, or use the browser).

Next to above two links to my site (other permissions are explained there as well), you might also wish to see [What do the permissions that applications require mean?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/38388/16575) on this site here.

Comment: @Lucky `svc wifi enable|disable`. Done! Also, in my Android 4.2.1 and 5.0.2 the file `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` has SSID and password in plain text. :) Not to mention Play Services has access to all of it.

Comment: @Lucky & Firelord: You go far beyond the question now. Please discuss that ***in chat*** :) For an app to enable/disable WiFi requires the `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE` permission (yes, you can do that via ADB because ADB has elevated privileges). But discussing the topic at this level only might confuse the OP (unless asked for *in another question*).