# How to get a complete list of actual app permissions for a given app (android)

Tags: security, permissions

Is there a way in the UI (eg without having to download/extract the `.adb` and open the app's `AndroidManifest.xml` file) to view the complete list of permissions that are requested by a given app?

Note I'm trying to get the actual list of permissions

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission

I'm not asking for the over-simplified human-readable permissions:

- [Map human-readable permissions to actual permissions (android reference documentation)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241793/map-human-readable-permissions-to-actual-permissions-android-reference-document)

How can I get a complete list of permissions for a given app?

Comment: I don't use play store. I'd prefer if this were do-able from Android itself, and not some closed-source app.

Comment: What about an open source app: https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX? Disclosure: I'm the author of the app.

Comment: I am a happy user of the app by @IrfanLatif

Comment: "Permission Manager X can run only in primary user account / device owner profile" :(

Comment: That's a closed source feature: https://mirfatif.github.io/PermissionManagerX/help/help.html#faq22. `adb shell dumpsys package` is the easy way though, without requiring any third party app.

Comment: The application named App Manager available in F-Droid allows the user to see all permissions, regardless of whether the app is installed for the primary user or secondary users.

Comment: Next to the excellent app by @IrfanLatif there are [several other apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_inspect) to inspect apps, not only [for permissions](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions) but also for other resources (Manifest, [libraries / tracking modules](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admodules) and more). Apologies for shameless self-promotion – but we learned here that apps get unlisted, and my lists are kept updated ;)