# What do ACCESS_WIFI_STATE and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE allow apps to see?

Tags: permissions

I'm finding very limited info on what the permissions ACCESS_WIFI_STATE and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE allow apps to do or see

What do these permissions actually do, and what information if any do they give to apps e.g your provider or WIFI SSID (even with location services etc turned off)?

Comment: Have you seen the information posted on SO here? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458772/whats-the-difference-between-access-network-state-access-network-state-and-wi#:~:text=ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE%20is%20needed%20for%20accessing,%2DFi%20connectivity%20in%20particular).

Comment: I have but I was concerned about it being outdated now, I also had a hard time understanding it so not sure if it answers my question

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. We have a canonical question about permissions on [What do Android application permissions mean?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/38388/44325). Let us know if it helps or not, thanks.